# How to Join Multiple Reference Tables Based on a String

Tags: excel, excel-formula, db2

Suppose that I am given three sheets to pull data from and I need to get repeating data back from those sheets. Essentially for each user in a user group, find all the permissions associated from another group and display given permissions. My sheets are setup as such. **(Assume top left is A1)**

#### First Table (User Sheet)

```
Username    Group
GPARR11     ACC-ADMIN
LPARR11     PRT-MGR
CSMITH      VP-SALES
```

#### Second Table (Permissions Sheet)

```
Group       Ref Table Rows  Switches
ACC-ADMIN   500             YNYNNNYN
ACC-ADMIN   502             YNYYY
ACC-ADMIN   503             NYNYYN
PRT-MGR     500             NNNYNNNYN
PRT-MGR     633             YNYNNNYNNY
VP-Sales    500             NYNYNNNYNY
VP-Sales    999             NYNYNYNYNYNNYNNYNYNN
```

#### Final Table (Reference Sheet)

*This sheet get's it's reference from the third column in the second sheet. So if a character is `Y` then it has that permission enabled `N` then it doesn't.*

```
Ref Table Switch Row    Sequenc #   Permission
500                        1        Access G&B
500                        2        Access Call
500                        3        Access A/R
633                        1        Modify G&B
633                        2        Modify Call
633                        3        Modify Memos
999                        1        Delete G&B
```

#### What I'm expecting to see

```
Username    Group       Permission    Enabled
GPARR11     ACC-ADMIN   Access G&B    TRUE
                        Access Call   FALSE
                        Access A/R    TRUE

LPARR11     PRT-MGR     Access G&B    FALSE
                        Access Call   FALSE
                        Access A/R    FALSE
                        Modify G&B    TRUE
                        Modify Call   FALSE
                        Modify Memos  TRUE

CSMITH38    VP-SALES    Access G&B    FALSE
                        Access Call   TRUE
                        Access A/R    FALSE
```

#### ADDT'L Info

Essentially the way that the information is supposed to flow to get each of the expected outputs is as follows. For each Username match their group name with the group name in the second sheet. From there the `Ref Table Rows` would tell you which rows are allowed to be returned, mapping the `Switches` `(YNYNYN)` with the respective Ref Table Rows from the reference sheet. The sequence number is there to determine which permission matches with the respective Switch. 1 is first char, 2 the second char, etc.. and determines whether it returns true or false on the output.

Looking at `GPARR11` the `ACC-ADMIN` matches with `ACC-ADMIN` in the permissions table. There are three `Ref Table Rows` associated with `ACC-ADMIN`, `500`, `502`, `503`. Each row has `Switches` that correspond to the `Reference Table`. So it will pull ALL permissions from `500`, `502`, `503`, and then check the `switch` to determine if each permission from the `ref rows` is `TRUE` or `FALSE`

Is there a way that this can be done with a formula?

Comment: Please, rewrite your question with complete `CREATE TABLE` statements for each of 3 participating tables to define them and `INSERT INTO MYTAB VALUES (...), ..., (...)` statements for each of them to get some sample data. Don’t use pictures - nobody wants retyping DDL and data for you. Note, that data in tables is not ordered by default - you have to specify the way how to order the table data based on table contents (may be with some surrogate column like ID). Finally, show the result desired on the sample data you provided.

Comment: Please add column names and provide more details - what is 23 in table 3, what is the difference of col2 and col3 in table 3, what is the diffeence of col 4 and col5 in table 3 etc.

Comment: @MarkBarinstein I'm not sure what you mean by the "Create Table", I rarely post in the excel section so I'm not familiar with the formatting or expectations here. I did, however, remove the images to give people a way to copy and paste better.

Comment: @MichaelTiefenbacher I provided column names and revised my information to make it easier to understand. It's a complex issue so It's hard to nail it down.

Comment: @xTwisteDx Db2 stores data in tables. So, if you want to get a solution with Db2, then it would be good enough to help us with providing statements for table creation and populating them with sample data on your own to not make others do this work for you...

Comment: @MarkBarinstein ohhh. Apologies, I sincerely thought it was clear I'm trying to do this in excel. I have it tagged w/ excel and excel-formula and clearly ask "Anyway this can be done with a formula." I will, however, attempt to do this with a query as that would be optimal. Thank you for the reply, I'm going to give this a try on Monday when I return to work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this as is:

```
WITH 
  TAB1 (Username, Group) AS
(VALUES
  ('GPARR11', 'ACC-ADMIN')
, ('LPARR11', 'PRT-MGR  ')
, ('CSMITH ', 'VP-SALES ')
)
, TAB2 (Group, Ref, Switches) AS
(
VALUES
  ('ACC-ADMIN', 500, 'YNYNNNYN')
, ('ACC-ADMIN', 502, 'YNYYY')
, ('ACC-ADMIN', 503, 'NYNYYN')
, ('PRT-MGR  ', 500, 'NNNYNNNYN')
, ('PRT-MGR  ', 633, 'YNYNNNYNNY')
, ('VP-SALES ', 500, 'NYNYNNNYNY')
, ('VP-SALES ', 999, 'NYNYNYNYNYNNYNNYNYNN')
)
, TAB3 (Ref, Sequence, Permission) AS
(
VALUES
  (500, 1, 'Access G&B  ')
, (500, 2, 'Access Call ')
, (500, 3, 'Access A/R  ')
, (633, 1, 'Modify G&B  ')
, (633, 2, 'Modify Call ')
, (633, 3, 'Modify Memos')
, (999, 1, 'Delete G&B  ')
)
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN ROWNUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T1.Username, T2.Group ORDER BY T3.Sequence) = 1 THEN T1.Username ELSE '' END Username
, CASE WHEN ROWNUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T1.Username, T2.Group ORDER BY T3.Sequence) = 1 THEN T2.Group    ELSE '' END Group
, T3.Permission, DECODE(T.Flag, 'Y', 'TRUE', 'FALSE') Enabled
FROM TAB1 T1
JOIN TAB2 T2 ON T2.Group = T1.Group
CROSS JOIN xmltable
(
'let $n := substring(replace($s, "(.)", " $1"), 2) for $id in tokenize($n, " ") return <i>{string($id)}</i>' 
passing 
  t2.switches as "s"
columns 
  seq for ordinality
, flag char(1) path '.'
) T
JOIN TAB3 T3 ON T3.Ref = T2.Ref AND T3.Sequence = T.Seq 
ORDER BY T1.Username, T2.Group, T3.Sequence;
```

The result is:

```
|USERNAME|GROUP    |PERMISSION  |ENABLED|
|--------|---------|------------|-------|
|CSMITH  |VP-SALES |Access G&B  |FALSE  |
|        |         |Delete G&B  |FALSE  |
|        |         |Access Call |TRUE   |
|        |         |Access A/R  |FALSE  |
|GPARR11 |ACC-ADMIN|Access G&B  |TRUE   |
|        |         |Access Call |FALSE  |
|        |         |Access A/R  |TRUE   |
|LPARR11 |PRT-MGR  |Access G&B  |FALSE  |
|        |         |Modify G&B  |TRUE   |
|        |         |Access Call |FALSE  |
|        |         |Modify Call |FALSE  |
|        |         |Access A/R  |FALSE  |
|        |         |Modify Memos|TRUE   |
```

[dbfiddle link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=f88165ebef091b82ad9094f9e2066f9d).